# How to run a Jenkins build if another three build in chain were successful?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

```
Build_1 --  Build_2.1 -- build_2.1.1 -- Build_3
       \--  Build_2.2 -----------------/
```

Hello.

I need an advice how to create such workflow in Jenkins. **Build_3** should start only if **build_2.1**, **build_2.1.1** and **build_2.2** were succeeded.

I tried to use Promotion plugin, but it does not allow set **build_2.1.1** as criteria because it is not downstream job for **build_1**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use default config on job?
On config you can add **post-build** action:
[image]
Add this action and config all your jobs.
Or I did not understand you?